# Reading raster directory with GDAL

Tags: c++, gis, gdal

Is it possible to read an entire directory of Geo - Tiff files "automatically" with GDAL C++ API or do I have to iterate manually on each file and open it with `GDALOpen()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate and open each file.